# How is the Date/Time formatted in Android notifications?

Tags: android, datetime

What does the Android OS use to format Dates and Times in notifications?

I assumed it used [DateUtils.formatSameDayTime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#formatSameDayTime%28long,%20long,%20int,%20int%29), but it does not exactly do that. The logic appears the same, but the format is not exactly the same. For instance, a notification will show me "2013-08-06" (based on my System Settings) when formatSameDayTime returns "8/6/13".

**Edit:**

Here's my current solution. But is it the best?

```
public static final CharSequence formatSameDayTimeCustom(Context context, long then) {
    if (DateUtils.isToday(then)) {
        return DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context).format(new Date(then));
    }
    else {
        final String format = Settings.System.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.DATE_FORMAT);
        return new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(new Date(then));
    }
}
```

Comment: Which `dateStyle` are you using?

Comment: I tried DateFormat.DEFAULT and DateFormat.SHORT both.